# Using Wubi to install Ubuntu Studio with pre downloaded image

Tags: wubi, ubuntu-studio

I am running Windows 8 x64 Enterprise, and have downloaded the Ubuntu Studio 12.10 x64 ISO. I place wubi.exe and the ISO in the same folder, and run it as administrator. But Wubi still attempts to download the stock 12.10 ISO. The Studio ISO also has a wubi.exe on it, but even that one tries to download the stock image. Is there a way to get this to work? Or does wubi support only stock Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

`Wubi` doesn't support `Ubuntu Studio`... yet. There is a plan to support it from `13.04`. It's possible to install it through some workarounds, but it's probably only for adventurous users. See ref [here](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2012/10/tricking-wubi-installing-xubuntu.html) (which talks about installing `Xubuntu` but the same technique can be used with a caveat contained on the bottom of that post)

Another point - if you have Windows 8 preinstalled, or are booting via `UEFI` (i.e. using a `GPT` partitioned disk), `Wubi` won't work at all.

If you do want to try it out you could see whether there is a `13.04` version of `Wubi.exe` available but that would be off-topic for Askubuntu since it's a development release.